# Read a file residing inside a jar being called from another jar file

Tags: java, xml, file, jar, classloader

I have two jar files (Lets say jar1 and jar2). There is one xml file inside a jar2. I want to read the xml file. i used

```
public void readXmlFile(){
InputStream resourceAsStream = MainFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.xml");
}
```

But now i am calling this function frm a class in jar1 using

```
File file = new File(jar2);
URL url = file.toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> compositeClass = cl.loadClass(XmlFileReader);
Method declaredMethod = compositeClass.getDeclaredMethod("readXmlFile");
Object newInstance = compositeClass.newInstance();
declaredMethod.invoke(newInstance);
```

Now I am getting FileNotFoundException as the xml file is being searched in jar1 and not in jar2, I do not know why is this happening. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The only reason that i can think of is that i am trying to load the file using the ClassLoader in jar2 and the the jar2 is being called from jar1 hence might be the classlaoder of jar1 is only being used so the file is being looked in jar1 and not in jar2..please help

Comment: did you try `compositeClass = Class.forName("fqcn.XmlFileReader", cl)`

Comment: also you could try `file.getAbsoluteFile().toURL()`

Comment: You could get the parent classloader with getParent(), until you have the "bootstrap" classloader. You can also try getSystemClassloader(). Both are methods of the ClassLoader class, and return a ClassLoader.

Comment: @ shyam : The solution provided by you is not working, i tried with both the approaches..

Comment: @ Gijs Overvliet : Your solution is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th Only solution i found is to set a System property using System.setProperty(key, value) in my jar1 as the path of the folder containing my both the jars. Then i read the system property back in my jar2 and then modified my readXml method like this

```
public void readXmlFile(){ 
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar2);
JarEntry entry = jarFile.getJarEntry("/test.xml");
InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);}
```